# Stream resumption in ejabberd is not working

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, ejabberd

**First Case:**

I am using PSI client in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and my ejabberd version is 16.03.

I am facing message lost issues hence i have gone through this link for stream management : http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html

When i send following request

```
<enable xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' resume='true'/>
```

Server response is ok for me, i.e

```
<enabled xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3" id="g2gCbQAAAANELTVoA2IAAAW+YgAMmKxiAAnx/A==" max="300" resume="true"/>
```

After some chatting with other user, when i send following Stream resumption request :

```
<resume xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' 
       h='0'
       previd='g2gCbQAAAANELTVoA2IAAAW+YgAMmKxiAAnx/A=='/>
```

I got the following error:

```
<failed xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3"><unexpected-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></failed>
```

I have tried all the ways like disconnect the network, kill application and offline the user. But stream resumption is not working.
I am not getting the problem, Please help me.

---

**Second Case:**

When i use following configuration in ejabberd.yml:

```
listen:  
  port: 5222
  module: ejabberd_c2s
  resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  stream_management: true
```

And start chatting after enables stream management. Then for the case of network disconnect and application kill, My all messages are storing in the offline queue (if i am not able to reconnect within 300 sec). In this process no one message is lost.

But my problem is this process is work only for mobile (ejabberd_c2s module). Web or Bosh is not supporting the stream management (ejabberd_http module). How can i use stream management for Bosh or web?